# Como mantener dialog abierto?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Este es mi XHTML de botones de un dialog, y no se que como evitar que se cierre el dialog cuando le doy guardar y los datos los tengo en requeridos, me explico: Quiero que al presionar guardar y los inputText estén vacíos no se cierre el dialog, pero si si estan llenos, pues se cierre

```
<p:commandButton value="Guardar" icon="fa fa-save" 
actionListener="#{soporteTipoBean.guardarSoporteDocumental}" 
process="@this id_main:panelParamSop" update="id_main:msgs 
id_main:nombreNitIPS 
id_main:dt_ConsultaSoporte"

styleClass="GreenButton" oncomplete="PF('NewParamet').hide();"  
onclick="PrimeFaces.cleanWatermarks()">
<p:resetInput 
target="panelParamSop" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Comment: Por favor, pon todo el código del XHTML,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agradezco a @Garrizano porque me dio la idea de como encontrar la solucion

```
<p:commandButton value="Guardar" 
                 icon="fa fa-save" 
                 actionListener="#{soporteTipoBean.guardarSoporteDocumental}"                                                                      
                 process="@this id_main:panelParamSop" 
                 update="id_main:msgs id_main:nombreNitIPS id_main:dt_ConsultaSoporte id_main:newParamSopor" 
                 styleClass="GreenButton"
                 oncomplete="handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args)"
                 >
                 <script type="text/javascript">
                  function handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args) {
                  if(args.validationFailed) {
                      PF('nombreWidgetVar').show();
                  }else {
                   PF('nombreWidgetVar').hide();
                      }
                  }
                  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo hago uso de JavaScript. Estas son las funciones que utilizo:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param {type} xhr
 * @param {type} status
 * @param {type} args
 * @param {type} dialogName
 * @param {type} formName
 * @param {type} widgetName
 * @returns {undefined}
 */
function handleSubmitRequest(xhr, status, args, dialogName, formName, widgetName) {
    dialog = jQuery('#' + dialogName);
    if (args.validationFailed) {
        dialog.effect("shake", {times: 3}, 200);
    } else {
        clearForm(formName);
        widgetName.hide();
    }
}

/**
 * 
 * @param {type} formName
 * @returns {undefined}
 */
function clearForm(formName) {
    jQuery('#' + formName).each(function() {
        this.reset();
    });
}
```

Y en el botón donde se ejecuta el guardar llamo a la función `handleSubmitRequest` de esta manera:

```
oncomplete="handleSubmitRequest(xhr, status, args, 'idDeDialogo','idDeFormularioDentroDeDialogo', PF('widgetVarDeDialogo'));"
```

Podrías agregar las funciones de Javascript en un archivo .js y cargarlo en tu vista para utilizarlo en varias vistas.